# Expand XML Schema to define a list of the currently defined top level tag

Tags: xml, xsd

[On this page, Microsoft a nice example of an XML Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256129.aspx) for an XML document representing a purchase order.

I would like to create something really similar, but in my case, the XML document will contain a whole list of purchase orders - i.e. multiple purchase order items. In the example at the link above, the Schema only represents one single purchase order.

What do I need to modify in the Schema to allow for multiple purchase orders? Let's say the tag will simple be `<purchaseOrders>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the schema:

```
<xs:element name="purchaseOrders">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element ref="purchaseOrder" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

`minOccurs="0"` is needed if `purchaseOrders` can be empty - if it must always have at least one `purchaseOrder` inside you can drop it.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256118.aspx) for details on `xs:element`